# Quickswap router function error when liquidity is added on WMATIC pair

Tags: blockchain, ethereumjs, web3.py, uniswap, polygon

i've been trying the functions from the router using the web3.py library. However am getting into troubles when calling the function with a WMATIC/Token liquidity pair and using USDC as currency to buy the token. The problem doesn't arise when the liquidity is added directly as a USDC/Token pair, using the exact same functions.

I've defined the qs_contract and the usdc contract as follows:

```
# public sender address
sender_address = ""

# This is the router plus abi definition
qs_router = "0xa5E0829CaCEd8fFDD4De3c43696c57F7D7A678ff"
with open("qs_router_abi.json") as qsJsonAbi:
    qs_abi = json.load(qsJsonAbi)
    qsJsonAbi.close()

qs_contract = w3.eth.contract(address=qs_router, abi=qs_abi)

# This is the USDC contract definition
usdc_contract_id = w3.toChecksumAddress("0x2791bca1f2de4661ed88a30c99a7a9449aa84174")

# Here goes the token created
token_to_buy = ""

# lets say budget to spend is $1
budget = 1000000
estimated_amounts = qs_contract.functions.getAmountsOut(
        budget, [usdc_contract_id, tokenToBuy]
    ).call({"from": sender_address})
```

As mentioned early, this functions goes well on USDC/Token pairs, but fails with WMATIC/Token pairs with the following error:

```
File "/home/basti/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 957, in call
    return call_contract_function(
  File "/home/basti/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1501, in call_contract_function
    return_data = web3.eth.call(
  File "/home/basti/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/web3/module.py", line 57, in caller
    result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str,
  File "/home/basti/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 181, in request_blocking
    return self.formatted_response(response,
  File "/home/basti/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 161, in formatted_response
    apply_error_formatters(error_formatters, response)
  File "/home/basti/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 61, in apply_error_formatters
    formatted_resp = pipe(response, error_formatters)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 667, in cytoolz.functoolz.pipe
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 642, in cytoolz.functoolz.c_pipe
  File "/home/basti/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/web3/_utils/method_formatters.py", line 554, in raise_solidity_error_on_revert
    raise ContractLogicError('execution reverted')
web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding the $WMATIC address to the path!

```
# lets say budget to spend is $1
budget = 1000000
estimated_amounts = qs_contract.functions.getAmountsOut(
        budget, [usdc_contract_id, wmatic_address, tokenToBuy]
    ).call({"from": sender_address})
```